# Would properly using an index prevent so many queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using MongoDB (with Mongoid) have a query which runs really really often in my app, I'm not sure I have proper indexes set up to make the queries more efficient, here is a snippet from my log when the query runs:

```
MONGODB (33ms) recipes_development['system.namespaces'].find({})
MONGODB (6ms) recipes_development['recipes'].find({})
MONGODB (0ms) recipes_development['system.namespaces'].find({})
MONGODB (0ms) recipes_development['users'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4f48469d4064241d860002d9')}).limit(-1).sort([[:created_at, :desc]])
MONGODB (0ms) recipes_development['users'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4f48469d4064241d8600032a')}).limit(-1).sort([[:created_at, :desc]])
MONGODB (0ms) recipes_development['users'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4f48469a4064241d8600008d')}).limit(-1).sort([[:created_at, :desc]])
MONGODB (0ms) recipes_development['users'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4f48469c4064241d86000273')}).limit(-1).sort([[:created_at, :desc]])
MONGODB (0ms) recipes_development['users'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4f48469d4064241d86000365')}).limit(-1).sort([[:created_at, :desc]])
MONGODB (0ms) recipes_development['users'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4f4846a34064241d86000910')}).limit(-1).sort([[:created_at, :desc]])
MONGODB (0ms) recipes_development['users'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4f48499a4064241c58000027')}).limit(-1).sort([[:created_at, :desc]])
MONGODB (0ms) recipes_development['users'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4f48499a4064241c58000027')}).limit(-1).sort([[:created_at, :desc]])
MONGODB (0ms) recipes_development['users'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4f48499a4064241c58000027')}).limit(-1).sort([[:created_at, :desc]])
... many more ...
```

How could I make this more efficient, or is the behavior I'm seeing typical?

***Update***

So the way I'm getting these records is via these scopes:

```
scope :active, where(:active => true)
default_scope order_by([:created_at, :desc])
```

Then I set the instance varibale in my controller thusly:

```
@users = User.active
```

Comment: What command in Mongoid are you issuing to get all these users?

Comment: Hey Jesse, I updated my question, I should have included that in the first place huh? Thanks for you help!

Comment: It looks like a classic n+1 problem... Are you sure that in the view you're not looking over all the recipes?

Comment: He's looking for users, recipes are not involved. But the query seems strange, there's no mention of `active` in it.

Comment: Joseph: is this whole output the result of single `User.active` invocation, or several?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an N+1 problem and you can fix it by using eager loading. An explanation of eager loading in Mongo for mongo mapper can be found here (search for "Eager Loading"):

- http://mongoid.org/performance.html
- http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html